# register webhooks on nodejs when order created

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks

I have a **shopify** store **mystore** and I have an nodejs app **myapp**. I need to do is when something happens on mystore a webhook will be created/registered in my nodejs app. I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks this package but it is not working for me and I don't think that it is the same thing that I want. **I just want that when let suppose order is created in store a webhook is registered**.

Answer (score 1):

if you just have to register a webhook you can use this code.
You just have to change the webhook topic and the endpoint.

This is for orders/create webhook registration

add **shopify-api-node** and **request-promise** packages and require them

```
const ShopifyAPIClient = require("shopify-api-node");
const request = require("request-promise");
```

then

```
const createOrderWebhook = await registerWebhook(yourShopDomain, yourShopAccessToken, {
    topic: "orders/create",
    address: "Your node app end point" //www.example.com/webhooks/createOrder,
    format: "json",
});
```

add your registerWebhook function

```
const registerWebhook = async function (shopDomain, accessToken, webhook) {
  const shopify = new ShopifyAPIClient({
    shopName: shopDomain,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  });
  const isCreated = await checkWebhookStatus(shopDomain, accessToken, webhook);
  if (!isCreated) {
    shopify.webhook.create(webhook).then(
      (response) => console.log(`webhook '${webhook.topic}' created`),
      (err) =>
        console.log(
          `Error creating webhook '${webhook.topic}'. ${JSON.stringify(
            err.response.body
          )}`
        )
    );
  }
};
```

for checking the webhook already not created at Shopify you can use following code

```
const checkWebhookStatus = async function (shopDomain, accessToken, webhook) {
  try {
    const shopifyWebhookUrl =
      "https://" + shopDomain + "/admin/api/2020-07/webhooks.json";
    const webhookListData = {
      method: "GET",
      url: shopifyWebhookUrl,
      json: true,
      headers: {
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token": accessToken,
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    let response = await request.get(webhookListData);
    if (response) {
      let webhookTopics = response.webhooks.map((webhook) => {
        return webhook.topic;
      });
      return webhookTopics.includes(webhook.topic);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("This is the error", error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not create/register a new webhook when the order created.

Webhooks are a tool for retrieving and storing data from a certain event. They allow you to register an https:// URL where the event data can be stored in JSON or XML formats. Webhooks are commonly used for:

- Placing an order
- Changing a product's price
- Notifying your IM client or your pager when you are offline
- Collecting data for data-warehousing
- Integrating your accounting software
- Filtering the order items and informing various shippers about the order
- Removing customer data from your database when they uninstall your app